# What triggered Hermione's epiphany?

Tags: harry-potter

As a reader, we know many things that other characters don't know, such as Harry being a Parselmouth (until revealed). Before a Quidditch match (or practise), Hermione becomes very enlightened to a idea regarding the Hogwarts' monster.

In the second novel, the following is found:

> “Harry — I think I've just understood something! I've got to go to the library!”
>
> And she sprinted away, up the stairs.
>
> “What does she understand?” said Harry distractedly, still looking around, trying to tell where the voice had come from.
>
> “Loads more than I do,” said Ron, shaking his head.
>
> “But why’s she got to go to the library?”
>
> “Because that’s what Hermione does,” said Ron, shrugging. “When in doubt, go to the library.”

It seems more than just a guess, but something very factual. What triggered Hermione to become so definite?

Comment: Can you provide some surrounding context for this quote, to make it easier for people to find?

Comment: She's probably just put together the facts that Harry's a Parselmouth and only he can hear it and it's Slytherin's monster so it's probably an ancient great snake so it could be a Basilisk. So off she goes to look in a library book. She may have worked out that it was getting around in the piping then as well, but the surrounding context gives us no reason to think so, really.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> He had just set foot on the marble staircase when he heard it yet again — 
>   “Kill this time . . . let me rip . . . tear . . .”
>   He shouted aloud and Ron and Hermione both jumped away from him in alarm.
>   “The voice!” said Harry, looking over his shoulder. “I just heard it again — didn’t you?”

Hermione suddenly realises why no one else can hear it: because it’s speaking in words only Harry can hear and understand—Parseltongue.

We also know that she deduces it must be in the pipes, as when next they find her, she has a page about basilisks—torn from a library book—clutched in her fingers, with the word “pipes” written on the back.

Comment: Almost worthy of a question unto itself, that: why did she bother writing “pipes” on the back and tearing the page out of the book? Was she actually expecting to be attacked? If so, why not go full out and write, “Slytherin’s monster is a basilisk. It moves in the plumbing pipes, so it probably comes from the girls’ bathroom on the second floor.” on the back instead of semi-useful hints?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it would be a good question maybe you should ask it haha :P